# why move Constructor is not call?

Tags: c++, logic, copy-constructor

please look at the following example code:

```
    class testo
{
public:
    testo()
    {
        cout << " default " << endl;
    }

    testo(const testo & src)
    {
        cout << "copy " << endl;
    }
    testo(const testo && src)
    {
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }
    testo & operator=(const testo & rhs)
    {
        cout << " assigment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    testo & operator= (const testo && rhs)
    {
        cout << "move" << endl;
    }

};
```

and this is my function and main code :

```
testo nothing(testo & input)
{
return input;
}

int main ()
{
testo boj1 ;
testo obj2(nothing(obj1) );
return 1;
}
```

when i compile and run this code i expect to see :

```
default    // default constructor

copy       // returning from the function

move       // moving to the obj2
```

but when the code is getting execute it just show :

```
default 

copy
```

the compiler is Visual C++ 2015

Comment: Please add the code you used to test the class.

Comment: Remove the const qualifier from your move constructor/move assignment

Comment: sorry i forgot the function

Comment: test noting (test & input) { return test}

Comment: Compiler am smart. It sees that the output of nothing can go right into `obj2` without any extra screwing around, so it does, building the copy on return right into the initialization of `obj2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Move signatures are supposed to be defined as `T&&`, not `T const &&`. While there's nothing in the language stopping you from declaring something `T const &&`, it makes no sense in practical terms: you mean to move from this object, but it's `const` and therefore can't have its state changed? It's a contradiction of terms.

Comment: thank you for your answer but . removing the const keyword.. didn't helped